# Block override not working

Tags: overrides, magento-2.1.9, override-block

I am trying to override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link` with `Anshu\Custom\Block\Catalog\Widget\Link` but it is not working.
**Anshu/Custom/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link" type="Anshu\Custom\Block\Catalog\Widget\Link" />
</config>
```

**Anshu/Custom/Block/Catalog/Widget/Link.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\Block\Catalog\Widget;

class Link extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\Link
{

    public function getHref()
    {
        exit('test');
    }

}
```

**Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

It would be helpful, if any one can explain me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: have you checked your custom module entry in setup_module table ?

Comment: @AasimGoriya yes custom module entry is there in the setup_module table.

Comment: Please try with move module.xml in `Anshu/Custom/etc/frontend/module.xml` and check again

Comment: May this help you? --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326744/how-to-override-module-catalog-block-widget-link-php-in-magento-2/333629#333629